# How to download this sound icon from inspecting the html source?

Tags: python-3.x, image, web-crawler

I'm trying to download the sound icons

[image]

from this [url](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/love_1?q=love). When I inspect this element, I see the code for it is

```
<div class="sound audio_play_button pron-uk icon-audio" data-src-mp3="https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/uk_pron/l/lov/love_/love__gb_1.mp3" data-src-ogg="https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/uk_pron_ogg/l/lov/love_/love__gb_1.ogg" title="love pronunciation
                    English" style="cursor: pointer" valign="top">&nbsp;</div>
```

From this source, I do not see any image file. Could you please help me get this icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is loaded using the css property. You have to download the css file i.e https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/external/styles/oald10.css?version=2.0.42 which has the background images for the divs.

Search via classname -

```
phons_n_am a,
.top-g .phonetics .pron-us, .sound.audio_play_button.pron-us.icon-audio {
    background-image: url(../images/documents/audio_name_initial.svg);
}

phons_n_am a:hover,
.top-g .phonetics .pron-us:hover, .sound.audio_play_button.pron-us.icon-audio:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/documents/audio_name_playing.svg);
    -webkit-transition: background-image 100ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-image 100ms linear;
    transition: background-image 100ms linear;
}
```

To download the images use - prepend the urls with - `https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/external/`

Example - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/external/images/documents/audio_name_initial.svg

Comment: I see the link when pressing F12 as shown in this [picture](https://imgur.com/8lzITrn). I've tried to re-apply your method to get the sound icon in this [url](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/lover/47867), but to no avail. Could you please elaborate on this case?

Comment: Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484254/how-to-get-the-sound-icon-from-https-www-larousse-fr?noredirect=1#comment112259132_63484254).