# How to get the sound icon from https://www.larousse.fr?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I'm trying to download as png the sound icon from this [url](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/lover/47867).

[image]

I inspected the CSS and it shows that

```
.lienson:after {
        font-family: "fontello";
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        display: inline;
        content: '\e82c';
        color: #ff4b54;
        text-decoration:none;
        cursor:pointer;     /*gestion v.audio*/
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('./../fonts/fontello.eot?58255341');
  src: url('./../fonts/fontello.eot?58255341#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('./../fonts/fontello.woff?58255341') format('woff'),
       url('./../fonts/fontello.ttf?58255341') format('truetype'),
       url('./../fonts/fontello.svg?58255341#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.fontello {
    font-family: "fontello";
}
```

I guess the link to download is `./../fonts/fontello.svg?58255341#fontello` but could not figure out what is the full link?

Could you please elaborate on how to get this icon?

Comment: download fontello? [here](http://fontello.com/)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini What I need is the exact icon from that url. I could not find it on your given website :(

Comment: What's wrong with my question that it gets a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a png, it's a webfont.

So, either you odwnload it directly from the url, which i wouldn't recommend because it would potentially raise copyright issues. FYI in this case the font url is relative to the css file url.

Or you make a screenshot of the element, which raise similar issues oif you use it.

Or you search for that font online, which could be a fail, since fontello is a font building tool, and the font you're searching for could simply not exist in the public domain.

Comment: I download the html and take the css from those files. I have searched for this CSS after pressing F12 but to no avail. Could you please elaborate more on how to download it directly from the url. This is just for personal use.

Comment: You take the url from the css file from the inspector, you copy it to the address bar, add a slash to it, and then add the relative url. Fair and square.